# When I double click the node text editing is going some where

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

When I double click the node text editing is going some where, instead of the node. The below is the code and I don't know what is happening. I'm using AJAX to get the mxGraph XML from server side.

Edited source code as per comments

```
// Creates the div for the graph
mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
document.body.appendChild(container);
var xmlDocument = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
var decoder = new mxCodec(xmlDocument);
var node = xmlDocument.documentElement;
container.innerHTML = '';
graph = new mxGraph(container);
    graph.cellEditor.init();
        graph.cellEditor.textarea.style.position='absolute';
graph.setHtmlLabels(true);
graph.setPanning(true);
graph.setTooltips(true);
graph.setConnectable(true);
// Changes the default style for edges "in-place"
var style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();

style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
style[mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE] = mxEdgeStyle.ElbowConnector;
decoder.decode(node, graph.getModel());

var layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph, mxConstants.DIRECTION_WEST);
var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
layout.execute(parent);
```

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Adding following piece of code during initialization helped me

```
graph.cellEditor.init();
graph.cellEditor.textarea.style.position='absolute';
```

Comment: First editing it is working. Next time onward not working. See I've edited the source code above.

Comment: Just adding this helped me. Graph is global and I have done this during initialization

Comment: I called the below method in onclick event in div tag it worked. But it is efficient or not efficient not sure. function init() {
 graph.cellEditor.init();
   graph.cellEditor.textarea.style.position='absolute';
 }

Comment: ksholla20. At least you helped some way. Thanks. Lots of LOVE to you.